# Grouping in Linq in a not so well organized xml

Tags: linq, windows-phone-7, linq-to-xml, yql

Im using YQL to get some data and here is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<div id="content>
<div id="html">
<h3>City</h3>
<div id="movie">
    <h4>
        <a href="">movie 1</a>
    </h4>
<div>
<div id="movie>
    <h4>
        <a href="">movie 2</a>
    </h4>
</div>
    .
    .
    .

<h3>City 2</h3>
<div id="movie">
    <h4>
        <a href="">movie 1</a>
    </h4>
<div>
<div id="movie>
    <h4>
        <a href="">movie 2</a>
    </h4>
</div>
```

I want to populate a listbox in my windows phone app with the city name and its movies like this:

```
City 1
Movie1
Movie 2

City 2
Movie1
Movie 2
```

However, I'm getting stuck here since all the XML is inside the div with id content.

How could a make a LINQ statement to solve this?

Comment: Please post a well-formed XML sample, otherwise it is difficult to understand the structure of your input document. Currently you have several opened `<div>` without matching `</div>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to morph your posted input into some well-formed XML:

```
<div id="content">
  <div id="html">
    <h3>City</h3>
    <div id="movie">
      <h4>
        <a href="">movie 1</a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="movie">
      <h4>
        <a href="">movie 2</a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    .
    .
    .

    <h3>City 2</h3>
    <div id="movie">
      <h4>
        <a href="">movie 1</a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="movie">
      <h4>
        <a href="">movie 2</a>
      </h4>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then you can get a List with the code

```
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("input.xml");
    List<string> data =
        doc.Descendants("h3")
        .Union(
          doc.Descendants("div")
          .Where(d => (string)d.Attribute("id") == "movie")
          .Elements("h4")
          .Elements("a")
          ).InDocumentOrder()
        .Select(e => e.Value)
        .ToList();
```

[edit] Your initial request seemed to ask for a flat list result, your comment suggests you rather want a grouped structure so here is an adapted sample:

```
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("input.xml");
    var groupedData =
        (from movie in doc.Root.Descendants("div")
         where (string)movie.Attribute("id") == "movie"
         group movie by movie.ElementsBeforeSelf("h3").Last() into g
         select new
         {
             city = g.Key.Value,
             movies = (from m in g
                       select (string)m.Element("h4").Element("a")).ToList()
         }).ToList();

    // now use above list for data binding or 
    // in the simplest case just consume it with foreach:
    foreach (var group in groupedData)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("city: {0}:", group.city);
        foreach (var movie in group.movies)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(movie);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thx for formatting my xml. The Union method really brought me the results. But I forgot to mention that I have an object I want to populate with this values. One variable would be the city and the other the movies. How can I get these separated values using linq to I can populate it? Thxx

Comment: I will edit the post to show you some grouping code then that creates an anonymous type with a string property for the city and a List<string> of movies.

Comment: I got no results from the new linq using group by. But now that I know it better I may try to solve it here. Whenever I find a solution I will post it here. Thx!